# I want to hide the selected while updating using v-menu v-list

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

this v-menu and links how to hide selected input while editing that same

```
<v-list-tile-action>
    <v-checkbox v-model="sites" v-bind:value="item" @cnange="selectedRemove('site',item)"></v-checkbox>
</v-list-tile-action>

<v-list-tile-content @click="selectedRemove('site',item)">
    <v-list-tile-title>@{{item.name}}</v-list-tile-title>
</v-list-tile-content>
```

Answer (score 0):

From reading your question, seems like you want a customized combo box like in this [link](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/master/packages/docs/src/examples/combobox/intermediate/advanced.vue).

It gives you the ability to add/edit your own items and removes it from the options list after selected. When removed from the selected list, it is added again to the options list.

I hope this answer can assist you :)